# Why React list slice always delete the last row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have similar code in Angular and it works great. I tried to convert the code into React version. It works great except when I try to delete a row. Every delete click removes the last row. My expectation is to remove the row I'm clicking the "remove" button. I'm passing the index item that needs to be deleted. I provided the sample below and you can try it here as well... https://jsfiddle.net/w6cy0bx1/11/

```
class MineCts extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
items:[]
};
}

render(){
return(
<div>
  <div><button onClick={(event)=>this.add(event)} >Add</button></div>
  <div>
    This is sample:
    {this.state.items.map((record, index)=>{
    return(
    <table>
      <tr key={index}>
        <td> <input id="Name" value={record.Name} onChange={this.onDataChange}/> </td>
        <td> <input id="Counter" value={record.Counter} onChange={this.onDataChange} /> </td>
        <td><button onClick={(event)=>this.remove(event, record, index)} >Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    )
    })}

  </div>
</div>
)
}

onDataChange(e)
{
console.log(e.target.id)
this.setState({[e.target.id]:e.target.value})
}

add(e){
let rows = this.state.items;
rows.push({});
this.setState({items:rows})
}

remove(e, record, index){
console.log(record)
console.log(index)
let rows = this.state.items;
rows.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({items:rows})
}

}



ReactDOM.render(<MineCts />, mountNode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your feedback. It was very helpful. I learn that you need to have a unique key if you are working with React rows. It also helpful to use filter instead of "splice". I have to add on change event. I find it very helpful as soon as I compose one component into multiple components. I updated the solution so that the input fields will not be wiped out after removing a single row. I also realized that unlike Angular React only does one way binding and every data change has to be updated through the state. Here is the complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/wfcev8zb/30/. Special thanks to user2340824 for continues feedback.
here is the final code:

```
class MineCts extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
items:[]
};

this.add = this.add.bind(this);
this.onDataChange = this.onDataChange.bind(this);
this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
}

render(){
return(
<div>
  <div><button onClick={this.add} >Add</button></div>
  <div>
    This is sample:

{this.state.items.map((record, index)=>{
    return(
    <DetailTable record ={record} callOnChangeFunc={this.onDataChange} callOnRemoveFunc={this.remove} />
  );
    })}

      </div>
</div>
)
}

onDataChange(e, record)
{
e.preventDefault();
let rows = [...this.state.items];
record[e.target.id]=e.target.value;
rows[record.Id] = record;
this.setState({items:rows})
}

add(e){
let rows = [...this.state.items];
rows.push({Id: new Date().getTime(), Name:null, Counter:null});
this.setState({items:rows})
}

remove(e, record){
e.preventDefault();
let rows = [...this.state.items.filter(x=>x.Id!==record.Id)];
this.setState({items:rows})
}

}

class DetailTable extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super();
this.callOnChange = this.callOnChange.bind(this);
this.callOnRemove = this.callOnRemove.bind(this);
}
callOnChange(e){
this.props.callOnChangeFunc(e, this.props.record);
}
callOnRemove(e){
this.props.callOnRemoveFunc(e, this.props.record);
}

render(){
return (
<div>
  <table>  
      <tr key={this.props.record.Id} >
        {this.props.record.Id}
        <td> 
        <input id="Name" value={this.props.record.Name} onChange={this.callOnChange} /> </td>
        <td> 
        <input id="Counter" value={this.props.record.Counter}  onChange={this.callOnChange}  /> </td>
        <td><button onClick={this.callOnRemove} >Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>     
);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MineCts />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 4):

After a closer inspection, the issue is due to:

```
      <tr key={record.index}>
```

This isn't actually being set, you don't have a unique key for your children, so React doesn't know which of these children has been modified so when you remove one of them, its a little confused.

You will need to provide a unique key to each of your Records.

I updated your code and used `new Date().getTime()` as a quick way of getting a unique key.

I have a working example here at https://jsfiddle.net/xk4e1z2s/2/

You will see the value of each Record's unique key being displayed as they are added, and you will notice only the specific row is being removed.

The reason, after a row is remove the input fields are empty, is because you need to save your record's input values.

Comment: I tried your answer not working. I also used a new array like this let rows = [...this.state.items]; still does not work. It always delete the last row. You can try your solution here https://jsfiddle.net/w6cy0bx1/11/

Comment: My apologise as my answer was not correct. I have identified the issue and have now provided a working solution at https://jsfiddle.net/xk4e1z2s/2/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are right it needs key but still not working correctly without having the change event hooked properly. I updated the solution so that the input fields will not be wiped out after you enter the record. I also realized that unlike Angular React only does one way binding and every data change has to be updated  through the state. Here is the complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/wfcev8zb/30/

Answer (score 1):

You can do directly setState on your remove function.

I mean ;

```
remove(index) {
  this.setState({
    items: this.state.items.filter((s, sindex) => index !== sindex),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but It is not deleting the right index row. It always delete the last row. you can try your answer here https://jsfiddle.net/w6cy0bx1/11/